# Electron (Windows) Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined

Tags: javascript, electron

I am learning electron and when I use this line `app.dock.hide();`

> I am receiving the error Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined

Is this a windows issue? The training video is being done for a Mac PC. The entire code is:

```
const path = require('path');
const electron = require('electron');
const TimerTray = require('./app/timer_tray');

const { app, BrowserWindow, Tray } = electron;

let mainWindow;
let tray;

app.on('ready', () => {
  app.dock.hide(); // <-- Error happening here
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 500,
    width: 300,
    frame: false,
    resizable: false,
    show: false
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/src/index.html`);

  // Hides mainWindow if another app is clicked
  mainWindow.on('blur', () => {
    mainWindow.hide();
  });

  const iconName = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'iconTemplate.png' : 'iconTemplate.png';
  const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, `./src/assets/${iconName}`);
  tray = new TimerTray(iconPath, mainWindow);
});
```

This is supposed to hide the icon from the taskbar. Any ideas of why windows throws a fit?

Comment: On what line are you getting this error?

Comment: app.dock.hide();

Comment: Check `app` and/or `dock` are defined.

Comment: @DavidBrierton You might want to first detect which operating system the application is running on before querying the `dock` object, as Windows doesn't have a `dock`, it's primarily a macOS feature.

Comment: Well that makes sense why it is failing then if it does not exist. Probably a If Statement figuring out the process.platform would be best then right?

Comment: Like so `if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
    app.dock.hide();
  }`

Comment: You seem to want something like "minimize to tray". You can listen to the `minimize` and `restore` events of the mainWindow and then use `mainWindow.setSkipTaskbar()` to set the visibility of the taskbar icon. You can also initiate your mainWindow with the `skipTaskbar: true` option.

Comment: @RoyalBingBong I believe you are the Electron Master!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364167/what-is-the-equivalent-for-app-dock-hide).

In order to make the window not show in the taskbar, you can either call `win.setSkipTaskbar(true);` or add `skipTaskbar` to the options passed to the new `BrowserWindow`:

```
{
    // ...
    skipTaskbar: true,
    // ...
}
```