# What is the equivalent for app.dock.hide();

Tags: javascript, electron

I currently working on an electron tray application. For Mac, the electron framework has a function for hiding the app in the dock.

```
app.dock.hide();
```

I try to run this on a Windows machine and get an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined
```

Now I am looking for an equivalent functionality for Windows to hide the app in the taskbar.

[image: electron app in dock]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mac OS X is application-oriented, whereas Windows is window-oriented...

[`app.dock.hide ()`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appdockhide-macos) Is indeed tagged as macOS only.

In order to make the window not show in the taskbar, you can either call:

```
win.setSkipTaskbar (true);
```

Or add `skipTaskbar` to the options passed to the new BrowserWindow:

```
{
    // ...
    skipTaskbar: true,
    // ...
}
```

Comment: does `skipTaskbar: true` work for both windows and mac or i should add `process.platform` check in case of mac we run `app.dock.hide();` else we run `win.setSkipTaskbar(true);`

Comment: `skipTaskbar: true` doesn't work for macOs

Comment: For me, neither works on macOS Ventura.